# I have started using AWS services for uploading images and uploading time it is working fine but while retrieving it is not working

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services

I am trying to pass the key in the API but in response, I am not url of that image.

I am using multer S3 for uploading images.

While uploading that URL is generating but in GET API resonse it is not coming.

How to get that URL.
Below is my code:-

```js
//node js code
var multer  = require('multer')
//var upload = multer({ dest: 'public/uploads/' });


var aws = require('aws-sdk');
var multerS3 = require('multer-s3');

aws.config.loadFromPath('./config.json');
aws.config.update({
    signatureVersion: 'v4'
});
var s0 = new aws.S3({})

var upload = multer({
    storage:multerS3({
        s3:s0,
        bucket:'bucketName',
        contentType: multerS3.AUTO_CONTENT_TYPE,
        acl: 'public-read',
        metadata: function (req, file, cb) {
            cb(null, {fieldName: file.fieldname});
        },
        key: function (req, file, cb) {
      cb(null, Date.now().toString())
    }
    })
})
//for posting
router.post('/profile/upload', upload.single('event_logo'), function(req, res, next){
    console.log("req.file",req.file);
    res.send(req.file);
});
//for retrieving
router.get('/profile/get/:id',function(req,res){
    var item = req.params.id;
    var params = {Bucket: 'bucketName', Key : req.params.id};
    s0.getObject(params, function (err, data) {
        if (err) {
            return res.send({ "error": err });
        }
        res.send({ data });
    });
});

//This is the response I am getting while hitting get Api
{
    "data": {
        "AcceptRanges": "bytes",
        "LastModified": "2017-07-01T10:54:26.000Z",
        "ContentLength": 225100,
        "ETag": "\"b10557805b4ffd815f888eb9e60a9266\"",
        "VersionId": "null",
        "ContentType": "image/png",
        "Metadata": {
            "fieldname": "event_logo"
        },
        "Body": {
            "type": "Buffer",
            "data": [
            
                209,
                155,
                158,
                166,
                9,
                119,
                32,
                116,
                73,
                95,
                193,
                52,
                190,
                19,
                64,
                146,........
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: .single method is used for text only types. Use `upload.any`

Comment: So you are sure the image is saved on S3 right? if so it should be saved in the specified bucket with the filename being the `id`. Then when you call the `get` endpoint passing it that same `id` it should find it and return the image as data, as it currently happens: `"Body": { "data": [ ... `

Comment: Yes images are saving in bucket I have created @Arpit Solanki

Comment: Yes images are saved and key is generating which I am passing as an id and bucket also I have checked link is generating but in GET method, I am not getting any link or location in response @DianaLog

Comment: Issue is resolved I just changed getObject to upload.It is working fine now